# Filtering SharePoint ListItems based on Modified By

Tags: sharepoint

I am writing custom coding for retrieving SharePoint list items based on modified by field. Can any one tell me how to get on object modeling.The code is like

```
        SPSite objsite = new SPSite("sitename");
        SPWeb objweb = objsite.OpenWeb();
        SPDocumentLibrary docs = objweb.Lists["Shared Documents"] as SPDocumentLibrary;
        Console.WriteLine(docs.ItemCount);`enter code here`
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = @"<where><eq><FieldRef Name='peoplenames'                      LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='User'>1;#1</Value></eq></where>";
        query.RowLimit = 5;`enter code here`
        SPListItemCollection items = docs.GetItems(query);
        if (items.Count == 0)
            return;
        else
        {
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item["peoplenames"]);
            }
        }
```

When i am trying to print values it shows exception.

Answer (score 1):

The modified by field  internal name is Editor. Your CAML query should be something like this

```
<Where>  
    <Contains> 
      <FieldRef Name='Editor' LookupValue='TRUE' />  
      <Value Type='Text'>User Display Name</Value> 
    </Contains>
</Where>
```